# How to get payment response from paypal as boolean in django?

Tags: django, paypal

I am using Paypal api for my Django website.I am able to make payment but don't know how to get payment response from paypal server as either True or False.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you are currently doing, I can only share the best solution.

Create two routes, one for 'Create Order' and 'Capture Order', [documented here.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls) These routes should return/output only JSON data (no HTML or text).

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

In the Capture Order route, before returning the JSON, examine the response for a PayPal transaction ID in the payments object and store this information in your database. If there is a new transaction ID, its status should be 'COMPLETED' or 'PENDING'.  In the latter case, flag it for manual review in PayPal.com